# Replace header of one column by file name

Tags: bash, awk

I have about 100 comma-separated text files with eight columns.

Example of two file names:

```
sample1_sorted_count_clean.csv 
sample2_sorted_count_clean.csv
```

Example of file content:

```
Domain,Phylum,Class,Order,Family,Genus,Species,Count
Bacteria,Proteobacteria,Alphaproteobacteria,Sphingomonadales,Sphingomonadaceae,Zymomonas,Zymomonas mobilis,0.0
Bacteria,Bacteroidetes,Flavobacteria,Flavobacteriales,Flavobacteriaceae,Zunongwangia,Zunongwangia profunda,0.0
```

For each file, I would like to replace the column header "Count" by sample ID, which is contained in the first part of the file name (sample1, sample2)

In the end, the header should then look like this:

```
Domain,Phylum,Class,Order,Family,Genus,Species,sample1
```

If I use my code, the header looks like this:

```
Domain,Phylum,Class,Order,Family,Genus,Species,${f%_clean.csv}
```

```
for f in *_clean.csv; do echo ${f}; sed -e "1s/Domain,Phylum,Class,Order,Family,Genus,Species,RPMM/Domain,Phylum,Class,Order,Family,Genus,Species,${f%_clean.csv}/" ${f} > ${f%_clean.csv}_clean2.csv; done
```

I also tried:

```
for f in *_clean.csv; do gawk -F"," '{$NF=","FILENAME}1' ${f}  > t && mv t ${f%_clean.csv}_clean2.csv; done
```

In this case, "count" is replaced by the entire file name, but each row of the column contains file name now. The count values are no longer present. This is not what I want.

Do you have any ideas on what else I may try?
Thank you very much in advance!

Anna

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are ok with `awk`, could you please try following.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} FNR==1{var=FILENAME;sub(/_.*/,"",var);$NF=var} 1' *.csv
```

***EDIT:*** Since OP is asking that after 2nd underscore everything should be removed in file's name then try following.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} FNR==1{split(FILENAME,array,"_");$NF=array[1]"_"array[2]} 1' *.csv
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation for above code here.

```
awk '                              ##Starting awk program from here.
BEGIN{                             ##Starting BEGIN section of code from here, which will be executed before Input_file(s) are being read.
  FS=OFS=","                       ##Setting FS and OFS as comma here for all files all lines.
}                                  ##Closing BEGIN section here.
FNR==1{                            ##Checking condition if FNR==1 which means very first line is being read for Input_file then do following.
  split(FILENAME,array,"_")        ##Using split of awk out of box function by splitting FILENAME(which contains file name in it) into an array named array with delimiter _ here.
  $NF=array[1]"_"array[2]          ##Setting last field value to array 1st element underscore and then array 2nd element value in it.
}                                  ##Closing FNR==1 condition BLOCK here.
1                                  ##Mentioning 1 will print the rest of the lines for current Input_file.
' *.csv                            ##Passing all *.csv files to awk program here.
```

Comment: Wow. This is working nicely. Thank you. Can I also change the code that it removes everything after the second underscore, including the second underscore? So, add: "sample1_sorted" as column name?
May you also explain me what the sub-function is doing in this case?

Comment: @AennaPhD, please check my edit solution and let me know, will add explanation in sometime too.

Comment: @AennaPhD, added detailed explanation for EDIT code too now, please do let me know in case of any queries.

Comment: concise and elegant solution

Comment: @AennaPhD FYI since you're using gawk, if your goal is to modify the original files you don't need the loop and temp files shown in your question, you can just do `gawk -i inplace 'script' *.csv` and it'll update them all "inplace" (i.e. actually using a tmp file internally).

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 your explanation is easy to understand and the code is very nice. Thank you very much for your efforts!

Comment: @EdMorton This is much more elegant and efficient! Thanks !